# How to set the sorting order (asc/desc) of an array based on dynamically selected property

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an an array of `movie` objects of the following structure:

```
$scope.movies = [
  {title: "some title", rank: 13, imdbRating: 828},
  // ...
];
```

and I would like to sort them by the property `title`, `rank` or `imdbRating` - selected with `<select>`, and by asc/desc ordering - selected with buttons. This is what I did, however, the ordering seems to get reset.

```
<select ng-model="orderProp" id="input">
    <option  value="title">Alphabetical</option>
    <option  value="rank">Rank</option>
    <option  value="imdbRating">Rating</option>
  </select>
  <button ng-click="orderProp='+'-orderProp;orderProp='-'-orderProp; orderProp='+'+orderProp " >Asc
  </button>
  <button ng-click="orderProp='+'-orderProp;orderProp='-'-orderProp;orderProp='-'+orderProp" >Desc
  </button>
  <li ng-repeat="movie in movies | filter:search:strict | orderBy  [orderProp]">
```

What I want to do is to choose an option to select the sorting property `orderProp` and if user clicks "asc" or "desc" buttons to re-order the list.

However, ordering does not know what categories I am sorting by so it can not do asc or desc correctly. Option get deleted as well visually if i click the asc / desc buttons.

Is there good solution to this?

Comment: Did the answer below address your question? If so, consider accepting

Answer (score 3):

The `orderBy` filter accepts two parameters: 1) the property, and 2) the order:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy:prop:isReverse">
```

So, in your case, you need to set the `isReverse` in the `ng-click` of a "Asc"/"Desc" buttons accordingly. You are already setting the property correctly with `<select>`.

```
<select ng-model="orderProp">
  <!-- as you do now -->
</select>

<button ng-click="isReverse = false">Asc</button>
<button ng-click="isReverse = true">Desc</button>

<li ng-repeat="movie in movies | orderBy: orderProp : isReverse">
```

It's also a good idea to set the initial value of these in the controller:

```
$scope.isReverse = false; // for ascending order
$scope.orderProp = "title";
```

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/nUYUUH9hKEvFXEqy9d0P?p=preview) - for illustration