# sorting products based on price in angular js

Tags: angularjs

```
[{
        "title":"Men's Polo",
        "sku":"menspolo",
        "img":"images/mens/mens polo front.png",
        "oldprice":675,
        "newprice":650,
        "latest":"latest",
        "desc":"Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amit Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amit Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amit"

    },
    {
        "title":"Women's Full Sleeve",
        "sku":"womensfullsleeve",
        "img":"images/womens/women polo front.png",
        "oldprice":666,
        "newprice":633,
        "desc":"Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amit Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amit Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amit"

    },
    {
        "title":"Women's Sleeve less",
        "sku":"menssleeveless",
        "img":"images/womens/womens hoodie front.png",
        "oldprice":599,
        "newprice":499,
        "desc":"Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amit Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amit Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amit"

    },
    {
        "title":"Women's Hoodie",
        "sku":"menshoodie",
        "img":"images/womens/womens t-shirts-front.png",
        "oldprice":680,
        "newprice":650,
        "featured":"featured",
        "desc":"Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amit Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amit Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amit"

    }
]
```

this is my product.json file, I am developing a store app and i wanted to set price filter in the page,

```
<form class="form-group form-inline">
    <input type="radio" name="filter" class="form-control"  ng-model="priceFilter" checked>&nbsp
    <label class="control-label">Low to High</label>&nbsp&nbsp
    <input type="radio" name="filter" class="form-control" value="reverse"  ng-model="priceFilter">&nbsp
    <label class="control-label">High to Low</label>
</form>
```

and the code above is my html code for filter's

```
<div class="ProductStore" ng-controller="ProductController">
            <div class="col-sm-4" ng-repeat="product in ProductList | filter:newprice | orderBy:newprice:priceFilter">
            <a href="#/details/{{ProductList.indexOf(product)}}" class="pdt-anchor">
            <div class="panel panel-primary" >
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <img ng-src="{{product.img}}" width="100%" height="100%">
                    <h4 class="pdt-title"><center>{{product.title}}</center></h4></a>
                    <center><p class="price"><span class="old">Rs.{{product.oldprice}}</span><span class="new">Rs.{{product.newprice}}</span></p></center>
                    <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Buy Now</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-block btn-warning">Add to cart</button>
                </div>
            </div>
```

this is the html code where the products are repeated,

what i want to do is when i click the "low to high" radio button, i want the products to be arranged in low to high price range, and when i click the "high to low" radio button, i want the products to be listed in high to low price range. how can i accomplish this task ?

Comment: Use ng-repeat="product in ProductList | orderBy: orderProp : isReverse" and set true|false for isReverse on radio button. For more details have a look at this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28917819/how-to-set-the-sorting-order-asc-desc-of-an-array-based-on-dynamically-selecte

Comment: will this reverse the products based on price ?

Comment: You need to specify the column on which this sorting you want. You need to replace "orderProp" with your column "newprice"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want `priceFilter` to be true (to sort in reverse order) when high to low is checked, and false (to sort in ascending order) when low to high is checked, you need to assign these values to the radio buttons:

```
<input type="radio" name="filter" class="form-control"  ng-model="priceFilter" ng-value="false" />
<label class="control-label">Low to High</label>

<input type="radio" name="filter" class="form-control"  ng-model="priceFilter" ng-value="true" />
<label class="control-label">High to Low</label>
```

Also, the order by in the view should be

```
orderBy:'newprice':priceFilter
```

and I'm not sure what your intention is with `filter:newprice`. It should probably not be there.

Comment: thanks JB Nizet i've got it right ! will please take pleasure to explain me the working of this filter ? i am a beginer and i will be pleased if you do so.

Comment: The documentation explains it quite well: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="search_drop_down">
   <select  class="select select-styled" ng-model="searchKeyword" id="brandSelection" >
      <option value="">-- Brand --</option>
      <option ng-repeat="pdt in products"  >{{pdt.brand}}</option>
   </select>
   <select class="select select-styled" ng-model="selectedPriceFilter" ng-options="option for option in options" ng-change="selectPriceFilter(selectedPriceFilter)">
      <option value="">-- Price --</option>
   </select>
   <input class="search" placeholder="Search" id="search" size="40" type="text" ng-model="searchKeyword">
</div>
```

//create scope variable options that has 'Low Price to High' and 'High Price to Low' values.
$scope.options = ['Low Price to High', 'High Price to Low'];

```
//add selectPriceFilter function that assign scope priceFilter to true / false based on condition
$scope.selectPriceFilter = function (selectedPriceFilter) {

    if (selectedPriceFilter == 'Low Price to High') {
        $scope.selectedPriceFilter = false;
    } else if (selectedPriceFilter == 'High Price To Low') {
        $scope.selectedPriceFilter = true;
    }
};
```